# Azure Function error in deployment using identity management

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I created an Azure function run through some API's and that all worked as intended. However, Once I added an async method to access the database using Identity management. I started receiving the below error.

```
Executed 'AzureFunction1' (Failed, Id=215dbf92-b461-4576-94a8-3fe917d67270, Duration=2470ms)Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have tried changing the connecting methods to async so that I could use `await` but I think there might be a syncing issue. Then again I'm really not sure which variable it's referring to. I'm having a hard time figuring out.

I've tried to get more information out of the error by placing the following info but I'm not getting much back anyway.

```
catch (Exception e)
            {
                var error = $"My error text";
logger.LogError(error + Environment.NewLine + e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace +
                                e.InnerException != null ? Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                                e.InnerException.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.InnerException.StackTrace : "");
            }
```

This is the method I added to Access the DB, I use this in a later function to add the int into some JSON.  (was testing with 0 before). Everything seems to be working fine in the Local version it's only erroring as soon as I test it in the deployment

```
public async Task<int> GetCountAsync(Record record)
        {

            try
            {
                //get access token from managed identity
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

                var accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");
  
                var connectionString = "Server = tcp:***,Port; Initial Catalog = ***";

                using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
                {
                    AccessToken = accessToken
                };
                conn.Open();
                var state = conn.State;
                using SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
                var withBlock = comm;
                withBlock.Connection = conn;
                withBlock.CommandText = $"SELECT COUNT(ID)AS 'count'\n";
                logger.LogInformation("Query: " + withBlock.CommandText);
                var reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

                reader.Read();

                int count = reader.GetInt32("count");
                logger.LogInformation("Count = " + count.ToString());
                return count;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var error = $"Error retrieving the count for this record: {record.ID}";
                logger.LogError(error + Environment.NewLine + e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace +
                                e.InnerException != null ? Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + e.InnerException.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace : "");
                throw new Exception(error, e);
            }
        }
```

Based off my output it's working until I log the query then it throws a 500 Internal Server Error with the error I showed at the start.

Comment: You should add more logs and see the possible grey code which is leading to this null ref error.

Answer (score 0):

In C#8 or later you can use syntax like this:

```
using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

but it should be trailed by ";".

Since you used "{}"
you disposed the connection immediately after creating.

From MS documents:
public override int GetInt32 (int ordinal);
ordinal is  Int32 the zero-based column ordinal.

So instead of

```
count = reader.GetInt32("count");
```

try to use

```
count = Convert.ToInt32(reader["count"]);
```

So your code should be like this:

```
using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
                    AccessToken = accessToken
             
                var state = conn.State;
                using SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
                var withBlock = comm;
                withBlock.Connection = conn;
                withBlock.CommandText = $"SELECT COUNT(ID)AS 'count'\n";
                logger.LogInformation("Query: " + withBlock.CommandText);
                conn.Open();
                var reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
               var count=0;
               if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                 if reader.Read()
                  {
               count = Convert.ToInt32(reader["count"]);
                 reader.Close();
                  }
             }
            logger.LogInformation("Count = " + count.ToString());
            return count;
}
```

Comment: It's not disposed imediately. It's based on using declarations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using

Comment: See some new explanations in my answer.

Comment: I believe you're reading OP's code wrong. There actually is a `;` behind the using declaration (it's just 3 lines lower because OP also uses an object initializer). `var myDisposable = new MyDisposable(){}` (without a `;` behind it so it disposes imediately) is not valid syntax so would not compile.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But I prefer explicit syntax. There are another erors as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback guys. Turns out my error was caused by a lack of privileges. I set up the function with a DB user that had write privileges. I didn't realise that the read and write privileges were separate.

Based off the feed got I did adust my code to make it a little more readable. This was the final result:

```
public async Task<int> GetCountAsync(Record record)
        {
            var count = -1;
            try
            {
                //get access token from managed identity
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

                var accessToken = await
                    azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");
                logger.LogInformation(accessToken);

                var connectionString = "Server = tcp:***,Port; Initial Catalog = ***";

                var query = $"SELECT COUNT(ID)AS 'count'\n";
                logger.LogInformation("Query: " + query);

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.AccessToken = accessToken;
                    conn.Open();
                    var state = conn.State;
                    using var comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    var reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            count = reader.GetInt32("count");
                            reader.Close();
                            logger.LogInformation("Count = " + count.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return count;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var error = $"Error retrieving the count for record: {record.ID}";
                logger.LogError(error + Environment.NewLine + e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace +
                                e.InnerException == null ? Environment.NewLine + e.InnerException.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.InnerException.StackTrace : "");
                throw new Exception(error, e);
            }
        }
```

I was able to set up the permissions in the DB by using the following queries

```
CREATE USER "AzureFunction1" FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER "AzureFunction1";
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER "AzureFunction1";
```